# Problems using memcpy to copy from a string to void pointer

Tags: c, memcpy, void-pointers

I want to use `memcpy` to copy a string to a void pointer (the reason I'm copying to a void pointer is that in my actual application I could be copying a variety of types, so I'm trying to be general), but using the bit of example code below I run into a problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ){
  char *str1 = strdup("Hello");

  void *str2 = malloc(strlen(str1)+1);

  fprintf(stdout, "str1 = %s\n", str1);

  memcpy(str2, str1, strlen(str1)+1);

  fprintf(stderr, "str2 = %s\n", *(char **)str2);

  free(str1);

  fprintf(stderr, "str2 = %s\n", *(char **)str2);

  return 0;
}
```

In this example I get a Segmentation Fault when trying to print out `str2`. Does anyone know why this does not work? Is it a problem with casting the void pointer to a `char`, or something more fundamental with `memcpy`? However, if I change the `memcpy` line to `memcpy(str2, &str1, strlen(str1)+1)` I can print out `str2` before freeing `str1`, but after freeing `str1` `str2` has also disappeared.

I do know that it will all work if I declare `str2` with `char*` rather than `void*` (and remove the casting in the output print statements), but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

*Update*: I've change the example code to avoid an initial memory leak.

Comment: Your cast is wrong. You don't want `*(char **)`, you just want `(char *)`.

Comment: Also, your initial `malloc` is nothing but a memory leak, `strdup` allocates its own memory.

Comment: @Kevin might want to put that in an answer, since it does actually answer his question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cast is wrong. You don't want `*(char **)`, you just want `(char *)`, and even that isn't really necessary.

Also, your initial malloc is nothing but a memory leak, `strdup` allocates its own memory.

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem exactly. In my actual application I do need to perform the `(char *)` casting as it's part of a code base where compiling is with strict flags that treat any warnings (which not using the casting will produce) as errors.